# A query works fine in MySQL and gives 'in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause' error in snowflake

Tags: mysql, snowflake-schema

MySQL query:

```
SELECT soc_pp_code, COUNT(soc_pp_code) AS count, rate
FROM subscriptions_history_sample_anonymized
GROUP BY soc_pp_code 
ORDER BY COUNT(soc_pp_code) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

[image: Result]

Snowflake Query:

```
SELECT soc_pp_code, COUNT(soc_pp_code) AS count, rate
FROM subscriptions_history_sample_anonymized
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2  
LIMIT 1;
```

> Error:  SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 49 'SUBSCRIPTIONS_HISTORY_SAMPLE_ANONYMIZED.RATE' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

Like the error message3 say, every column has to be in the group by or use an [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) like MIN for rate or what ever you need

```
SELECT soc_pp_code, COUNT(soc_pp_code) AS count, MIN(rate)
FROM subscriptions_history_sample_anonymized
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2  
LIMIT 1;
```